# How to find the % returning visitors through the Google Analytics API

Tags: python, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

It is visible on the Audience Overview page as a pie chart of Percent New Visitors vs % Returning Visitors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clarification: The pie chart actually shows % of Sessions by new and returning visitors, not % returning users. As zborovskaya stated, there is a ga:percentNewSessions which can be used (100 - %new = %returning session).

Answer (score 2):

There is no metric 'Percent New Visitors' and 'Percent Returned Visitors'. But you can use `ga:userType` and calculate %.

And also metric `ga:percentNewSessions` exists - the percentage of sessions by users who had never visited the property before. May be it will be helpful.